# Composition vs Inheritance - how this can help Unit Testing?

Tags: java, php, unit-testing

Why using Composition is more recommended for `Unit testing` approach?

It is related to the fact that by extending a class you have to test the entire API of the parent class too and by using Composition you have more control on the methods you want to use from the parent class?

Comment: It might be better to ask this [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I would say that in a manner of "Composition vs Inheritance" - Composition is **always** a better, more maintainable choice.

Only exception I can think of are database models in languages that don't support annotations.